# VirtualBox - connection between VMs, host and Internet, and access to containerized services running inside a VM

Tags: docker-compose, containers, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I have three VirtualBox VMs running different systems. I need all the VMs communicating between them and with Internet access.

Now, I have two network adapters configured for each VM. The first network adapter is configured with NAT and DHCP, for Internet access. The second network adapter is configured as "host-only", with a static IP. The communication among the VMs is ok, but I need to access some containerized services running inside one of the VMs. These services are running through `docker-compose`.

As I cannot configure port forwarding for a "host-only" adapter, I am searching for the best way to deal with this problem. Most of the results I find on the Internet suggest what I already did: NAT + host-only. So, what is the best configuration for VBox VMs running with static IPs, communicating to each other and to Internet, and allowing access to containerized services that run on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day searching for a solution, thinking the problem could be with the VBox network configuration, I discovered that the docker-compose file was restricting the access only to the localhost:

```
ports
- 127.0.0.1:8500:8500
```

To solve my problem, I just changed all this information to:

```
ports
- 8500:8500
```

Now, I am successfully accessing the services running in containers inside the VBox VM. I tried to access using my first configuration, which is NAT for the first adapter and host-only with a static IP for the second adapter, and using the bridged configuration. I got success with both.